# Conflict in reference assemblies

Tags: c#, wpf, reference, assemblies

I added refernence of System.Windows.dll to my project cos i need it some pages but lots of error pop outs like

> The type 'System.Windows.MessageBox' exists in both 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\PresentationFramework.dll'
>   and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\System.Windows.dll'

and

> The type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs' exists in both
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Profile\Client\PresentationCore.dll'
>   and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\System.Windows.dll'

and many more errors that says exist is both assemblies . How do i fix this?

Comment: so your using Siverlight and WPF in the same application?

Comment: yup i hav a WPF application , but i am moving a source code that is silverlight to WPF

Answer (score 0):

What about full qualifying the types you are using in your class and / or defining alias names for your using directives. Does this work ?

Comment: You meant something like the below answer?

Comment: Yep, something like this, you can also make an alias for your namespaces: "using SW = System.Windows;" in the heador of your files. If you have many of them maybe it is easier to remove the second reference and at first refactor your code using replacements(replace "MessageBox" with "SW.MessageBox") and so on..

Comment: the below answer doesn't work , i tried removing the assemblies that is in conflict but it will show different error because some code need that particular assemblies .

Comment: I know that you are needing these two assemblies, but basically if you do not want to explicit tell .NET what namespaces you are using for the types, the only way is to split your class into different assemblies to be sure. But i dont think you want to do this. In my opinion its the only way by using the namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try explicitly naming the namespace that you want to use.

Something like:

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]
private void SomeMethod()
{
    MessageBox.Show("SomeText");
}
```

or

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("SomeText");
```

Comment: does not work. even if it does , i have to type for like as many as the errors are.